# Node.js async.each throws "Callback was already called"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

This problem might seem like a duplicate of many others, but I can't find my mistake anywhere.

The problem is that async.each throws "Callback was already called". Here's the snippet (I named the async callback `done`, so it doesn't get confused with the other callbacks in my code):

```js
async.each(this.requirements, (requirement, done) => {
  // That thing here passes the result as a callback
  requirement.callback((result) => {
    if (!result) {
      // requirement not passed -> return error
      done(true); // LINE 42
    } else {
      done(); // LINE 44
    }
  }, data, params, bot);
}, (err) => {  // 'done' callback
  log.info('handler',
    `Handler '${this.label}' ${err ? 'failed' : 'succeeded'}`);
  // if any requirement did not pass, do not execute handler callback
  if (!err) this.callback(data, params, bot);
});
```

Here's the stack trace of it:

```
C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:837
          if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                           ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:837:34
    at requirement.callback (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\telegramjs\core\handler.js:44:11)
    at Requirement.exports.command.Requirement.callback (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\telegramjs\telegram\requires.js:21:5)
    at async.each (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\telegramjs\core\handler.js:39:19)
    at C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:2953:18
    at replenish (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:872:19)
    at C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:878:27
    at C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:840:18
    at requirement.callback (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\telegramjs\core\handler.js:44:11)
    at Requirement.callback (C:\Users\samuel\Code\node\sk22tgjs\node_modules\telegramjs\core\requires.js:19:5)
```

The interesting thing is that the issue only occurs if `done(true)` gets called. Nevertheless, the error occurs at line 44, not 42.

You can also see the corrupt code on GitHub, especially the `testing` branch: https://github.com/22sk/telegramjs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/22sk/telegramjs/blob/master/telegram/requires.js#L16 missing return statement to prevent `result` from getting called twice? (hence why the stack trace points to line 21)

Comment: Aaah, damn. Didn't think that far, thanks. Would you post it as an answer?

Comment: get rid of the arrow functions for clarity's sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a command isn't found, both the success and failure are being called rather than just the failure.

https://github.com/22sk/telegramjs/blob/5b85f04fe890a8fd32b373edb97bfebc923156b1/bot/telegram/requires.js

```
exports.command = new Requirement({
  label: 'command',
  requires: requires.has('message', 'text'),
  callback: (result, data, params, bot) => {
    const command = new Command(data.message.text);
    if (!command.valid || command.bot && bot.me.username !== command.bot) {
      // command is not valid or not meant to be handled by this bot
      result(false); // <--- ### Missing return ### --->
    }
    // command is valid and should be handled by this bot
    // write command into data
    params.command = command;
    result(true);
  }
});
```